# A message told thrice

Tags: story

In front of me, there's a shadow of a man; he speaks to me thus;

> (1) Despite your most desperate wishes, I am a bet you cannot beat. To be content with me is to know peace of mind. Know this: of people like you, the world is full. So very wrong of how far they are off. Of people who know me, there is a dearth.

He pauses; I feel a change; there's vivacity, I am infused with a force quite antithetical to the man's words. I hear the sound of his voice;

> (2) Forget where I am; forget my whole purpose. I am drunk with the vigor that shoulders your burden. May Heaven have mercy on the untroubled below it. Live such a life; no, *you must oppose it.*

He has disappeared. Behind me, there's writing on the wall, faded with time, subject to the whims of billions before me, written in charcoal chalk:

> (3)
>   [image: message]

There's silence. I drop to my knees to pick up note on the ground. He has left a clue for me that reads:  `"LOOK FIRST FOR THE ENDS, ONLY THEN THE BEGINNINGS."`

**The man has left me three secret messages, each equivalent in meaning,  and each four words or shorter. What are they?**

*Note: The secret messages come out of only the highlighted text; everything else is just poetic prose. Also, this is my first riddle like this, so I fully expect to give hints or make edits as necessary.*

Comment: Are you quite sure of the second symbol in #3?

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan If you're asking that, you likely already have the answer. Let's say I am sure. :)

Comment: Well, I know what that text says and what _sort_ of thing the overall answer must be; but although the text in #1 and #2 has the right sort of flavour, I haven't yet worked out what it _hides_ in either case.

Comment: Ah, figured out the first one. (Don't worry, I haven't been staring at it all this time.) [EDITED to add:] And the second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first message

> has last words of sentences ("look first for the ends") that, after removing a few letters, yield BE MINDFUL OF DEATH.

The second message

> has *first* words of sentences that, when you take the advice of its last sentence ("ends first"!) and reverse their meaning ("oppose it"), yield REMEMBER YOU MUST DIE.

The charcoal-chalk (is that a thing?) message consists, almost, of

> the tops of the letters IROMOTNEMEM, or MEMENTO MORI backwards. ("Ends first" in two senses: that's how we have to read, and the meaning is that we should pay attention to our own ends.)

Comment: Correct! Very nice. Idk if charcoal chalk exists but I had to make it work with my dark pen. :D